Powerpoint distorting flextable when using {officer}
When I run the code to produce the flextable within R it looks exactly as I want, but when I use the {officer} package to put it into a powerpoint slide it stretched the height, adding extra space between the lines. I think this is because of the NAs, but how do I correct it?
This df works:
df1 <-as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:8, 6*8, replace = TRUE), nrow = 8, ncol = 6))
df1 |> flextable(cwidth = 0.4, cheight = 0.1) |> fontsize(size = 8) |> width(j = 1, width = 0.5) |> padding(padding = 0) |> height_all(height = 0.2, unit = "cm") |> hrule(rule = "exact")

but this doesn't
df2 <- data.frame(
  Column1 = LETTERS[1:6],  # Letters in the first column
  Column2 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2))),  # 1-digit random numbers and blanks
  Column3 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2))),
  Column4 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2))),
  Column5 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2))),
  Column6 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2))),
  Column7 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2))),
  Column8 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2)))
)
df2 |> flextable(cwidth = 0.4, cheight = 0.1) |> fontsize(size = 8) |> width(j = 1, width = 0.5) |> padding(padding = 0) |> height_all(height = 0.2, unit = "cm") |> hrule(rule = "exact")

flextable seems to be handling NAs differently than numbers or characters

The problem is that font sizes are not applied to cells with empty strings (this also happens if you replace NA with ""). This issue is currently listed here: https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/153
The best workaround at the moment would be to replace all NAs with a whitespace.
df2 <- data.frame(
  Column1 = c(LETTERS[1:5], ""), # adding an empty string for good measure
  Column2 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2))),
  Column3 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2))),
  Column4 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2))),
  Column5 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2))),
  Column6 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2))),
  Column7 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2))),
  Column8 = sample(c(0:9, rep(NA, 2)))
)

# replace NAs and empty strings with whitespace
df2[(is.na(df2) | df2 == "")] <- " "
# alternatively, you can also set flextable defaults
# set_flextable_defaults(na_str = " ")


df2_flextable <- (
  df2
  |> flextable(cwidth = 0.4, cheight = 0.1)
  |> fontsize(size = 8)
  |> width(j = 1, width = 0.5)
  |> padding(padding = 0)
  |> height_all(height = 0.2, unit = "cm")
  |> hrule(rule = "exact")
)

my_pres <- read_pptx()
my_pres <- add_slide(my_pres, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")

my_pres <- ph_with(my_pres, df2_flextable, ph_location_type(type = 'body'))
print(my_pres, target = 'presentation.pptx')

